# Found screens with the same name nested inside one another

Tags: javascript, react-native, module, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I want to achieve [a native stack navigator for each tab](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#a-native-stack-navigator-for-each-tab). However I want different Stack navigator files for each tab. So I created different files but i'm getting a warning in the console:

> Found screens with the same name nested inside one another. Check:
>
> Home, Home > Home
>
> This can cause confusing behavior during navigation. Consider using
> unique names for each screen instead. at
> node_modules/@react-navigation/core/src/BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:364:14 in React.useEffect$argument_0

Also the the Home screen is nested inside Home screen.I tried changing the name of the Home from `Home` to `Homescreen` component still the issue persists.
[image]

Here are the functions in my files:

**Home.js**

```
function Home({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>Home screen!</Text>
      <Button title="Details" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Details.js**

```
const Details = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Details will appear here!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**HomeStackScreen.js**

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import HomeScreen from "../screens/Home";
import DetailsScreen from "../components/Details";

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import HomeStackScreen from "./HomeStackScreen";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === "Home") {
              iconName = focused ? "ios-home" : "ios-home-outline";
            }
            {/*other routes*/}
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
       {/*other tabs*/}
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: the tabScreen is named "Home" and your homeScreen is named "Home", this is what the error is telling you. Since the HomeStack is nested inside the tabScreen named home, it can't contain a screen named "Home" too